# Python List Comprehension: Squaring odds lambda

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

> List comprehension is typically used to filter and transform lists.
>
> Given the variable nums, whose value is a list of integers, write an assignment statement that assigns to the variable square_odds the list of the squares of the odd numbers in the list nums.
>
> You must use list comprehension

This is what I have so far but I get an error code:

```
nums = [square_odds**2 for square_odds in nums if square_odds %2 != 0]
```

I get this error code: you have not assigned to square_odds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing they want you to do this:

```
square_odds = [n**2 for n in nums if n % 2 != 0]
#         assign
# the variable
# square_odds 
#              the list
```